# PHP: convert all object elements from string to int

Tags: php

how to convert all object elements from string to int,

I have object with string values, like this:

```
    "data":
   {
       "usp": "50",
       "avsp": "60",
       "ca": "4",
       "inca": "4",
       "toq": "1",
       "t": "24",
       "wk": "0"
   }
```

how to convert all values in this object to int, to be:

```
    "data":
   {
       "usp": 50,
       "avsp": 60,
       "ca": 4,
       "inca": 4,
       "toq": 1,
       "t": 24,
       "wk": 0
   }
```

update:
I'm using Laravel "DB::selectOne" method
it returns 1 row results as object,
then I need to display this results as json "without quotes"

thanks,

Comment: Is it an object or an array? If it's an object, what type of object?

Comment: @AlpineCoder it's object return from DB selection (1 row)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, what class is the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($obj->data as $k => &$v) {
    $v = intval($v);
}
```

Test passed on 5.4.29.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to do string operations on it, just convert it into an array with `json_decode`. Decode it, then just use `array_map()` with `intval` then encode again.

```
$data = json_decode($json_string, true);
$data = array_map('intval', $data['data']);
$json_string = json_encode($data);
```

If it originated as an object with just some properties, you could apply it like this:

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true); // convert to array
$data['data'] = array_map('intval', $data['data']); // apply intval
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data)); // convert to object
```

Comment: it is not json, it is selection from DB return as object and I need to keep it as object

Comment: or `array_walk($data, function(&$v) { $v = (int) $v; });`

Comment: @mwafi if it's not JSON but rather an object, skip the `json_decode` party and proceed as suggested above

Comment: @mwafi since you left out some important parts, you can just skip those decoding part. The important part is casting it with intval

Comment: Neither `array_map` or `array_walk` will operate on an object though (unless possibly it implements ArrayAccess).

Comment: I receive: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @mwafi maybe you should post more pertinent info on the question, how is this object generated so that we'll know how this will be approached. Yes thats to be expected since this is an object. If this does contain just properties, you can just cast it to an array first, then reapply the `array_map()`

Comment: @Ghost I add this line in the post ( update: I'm using Laravel "DB::selectOne" method it returns 1 row results as object, then I need to display this results as json "without quotes")

Comment: Actually, I take that back, array_map will complain about passing it a `StdClass` but array_walk seems to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the number of fields the object has a use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function to convert from string to int.

```
$number_of_fields = count($data);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $number_of_fields) {
    $data[$i] = intval($data[i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the values of the array to integer using intval:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    $data[$key] = intval($value);
}
```

Simple!